# Junit Testing- Queue (not recognising all instances)

Tags: java, queue

I am testing a method for my queue and it is only recognising one instance. 
So when I run the test it says the result should be `Number of passengers is: 3.0`, instead of `Number of passengers is 13.0`
Any help would be great, thanks.
I have attached an image below:

[image: Image of test]

Comment: from [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
_"DO NOT use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then format it as code. This helps others more easily read and test your code."_

Comment: Isn't it easier to copy paste your code here instead of taking a picture, uploading and putting the link?

Comment: I'd like to try out your test on my own system, so I can help you work out what's going on.  Unfortunately, my IDE doesn't accept images as input.  Like most Stack Overflow users, I won't be able to help, unless you add your code _as code_ to the question.

Comment: Can you provide, the definition of totalPassengers() method?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It will help your question to get answered if you upload your code and tag your question properly.  For instance, if your question is regarding the js framework junit, please tag it with the junit tag.